# can I create a Discord account using their API?

Tags: discord

is it possible to create a Discord account from the api they have provided? not a bot account but an account that usually registers using an email and password...

If that's possible, what is the api route?

Comment: Create a new account on chrome, and inspect network activities with console, then you can see all routes, but i dont think they get one for creating acc

Answer (score 1):

researching the same thing, need to create discord account on a button click from external source through api's

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).